# AWS IAM Instance Profile Policy Placeholder For EC2 Instance ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to write a policy for an IAM instance profile role (a role which will be attached to an EC2 instance) and I want to use the EC2 instance ID to limit access to certain resource. For example

```yaml
- PolicyName: LogsPolicy
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 's3:PutObject'
        Resource:
          - arn:aws:s3:::somebucket/${EC2InstanceID}/*
```

(the instance can only write to the `${EC2InstanceID}` folder in the `somebucket` bucket and I want `${EC2InstanceID}` to be replaced with the actual instance ID I'm writing from.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html

[image]

I can use `${aws:userid}` as a placeholder for `${role-id}:${EC2InstanceID}` but I want just the `${EC2InstanceID}` (without the `${role-id}:` prefix)

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't think that is possible, the IAM policy language is simply not powerful enough to do that.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't expect to be able to take the `${role-id}:${EC2InstanceID}` string and do string manipulation to extract `${EC2InstanceID}` out of it. I was hoping there'd be a direct variable/placeholder that stands for the instance ID

Comment: You might be able to do it with a StringLike condition on user ID https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-userid.  Keep in mind though that hard coding an instance ID may not be a wise decision, as instances typically should be expected to come and go

Comment: @erik258 can you give an example for how it'd work? I couldn't understand it clearly from your link. and yes, I can't hard code the instance IDs, the instance ID can be anything